# Why can't I reference a global variable defined in a class?

Tags: python

```
class MyClass(object):
   code_mapping = {...}

 def get_name(code):

    code = code_mapping[code]
    ...
```

In this piece of code, it complains that 'code_mapping is not defined'. Isn't code_mapping is accessible to everything within MyClass?

Comment: It is available, but only via the class or self.

Comment: Oxymoron of the week: "Global variable defined in a class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize it with `self`. This will make it accessible by any function in the class by passing it with `self.<variable>` and then passing `self` as a function argument to anything you want to pass the variable to.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.code_mapping = {...} # if this will be a hard coded 

    def get_name(self):

        code = self.code_mapping[code]
        ...
```

Or you could do:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, code_mapping):
        self.code_mapping = code_mapping

    def get_name(self):

        code = self.code_mapping[code]
        ...
```

if you'd like to pass some code mapping as an argument to your class at its instantiation.

To create a class object from this where you want `{'code1' : 'name'}` you then initiate a class object like this:

```
code1 = MyClass({'code1' : 'name'})
```

And then `{'code1' : 'name'}` will be what is carried forth into whatever `get_name()` does and the value of `code` in `get_name` will be `name`.

Comment: Put it in a constructor....

Comment: Is the constructor necessary or optional?

Comment: Are you passing new arguments to `self.code_mapping` each time or is this going to be a hard coded variable

Comment: self.code_mapping[name], where 'name' is a variable.

Comment: @ling technically not needed but good practice. It is also how you pass variables to your class when you make a new class.

Comment: Added a bit of explanation to it.